# Are packages in Laravel 4 the same as libraries in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-4, libraries

I used to use CodeIgniter. In CodeIgniter whenever I had to create my own classes, I used to create a class in the library folder and used it as a library. In Laravel they use packages. In the documentation they also talk about creating your own packages. Are packages in Laravel 4 same as libraries in the CodeIgniter?

Comment: Packages in laravel are 3rd party libraries

Comment: then where should I create my own classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be common now is to put custom classes, exceptions, validation, etc. into a folder that is named in correspondence to your application.

For example:

```
| laravel
|    -- AppName/
|       -- Exceptions
|       -- Repositories
|       -- Validation
|       -- CustomClasses (your custom class name)
|    -- controllers
|    -- models
|    -- views
```

To include in composer, the easiest way is to include the classmap

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/AppName"
        ]
    }
```

If you would like to use psr-4 auto loading instead, there is a great free video on Laracasts to get you started https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading

Also, if you're a Laracasts member, the Where Do I Put This video is exactly what you're looking for with this question. https://laracasts.com/lessons/where-do-i-put-this

Answer (score 2):

Laravel's packages are third-party libraries from Composer.

Your own classes that don't fit in a controller/model can go wherever you want as long as you tell the autoloader where to find them. We use `app/libraries` and the PSR namespacing conventions. If you do so, you need to add `app/libraries` to the `composer.json` in the `autoload-->classmap` array.